# Apple Script: Copy file (being selected from prompt) to another location

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I am struggling with my Apple Script. I am asking to select a file and the selected file needs to be copied to another location. I am new to Apple Scripting, so probably made some mistake. I tried different versions with "copy" instead of "duplicate" or "alias" instead of "file", but nothing worked so far. Hope, somebody can help me figure this out.

This is what I scripted so far (I get an AppleEvent timed out):

```
set DefaultPath to POSIX file "/Users/jan/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/FOLDER/Test"
    set DestFolder to "/Users/jan/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/FOLDER/Destination"
    set theFile to (choose file with prompt "Select file:" default location (DefaultPath))
    tell application "Finder"
        duplicate theFile to folder DestFolder
    end tell
```

Comment: If you make your DestFolder reference a posix file, it should work. As written, it is a string and not a file reference.

Comment: thanks a lot, just a small changes and it works. So amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Finder doesn't support POSIX paths.

I recommend to use a relative path `path to library folder from user domain` and HFS paths (colon separated)

To satisfy the `location` parameter of `choose file` put the `alias` keyword in front of the (HFS) path

```
set cloudDocs to (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Mobile Documents:com~apple~CloudDocs:"

set DefaultPath to cloudDocs & "FOLDER:Test:"
set DestFolder to cloudDocs & "FOLDER:Destination:"
set theFile to (choose file with prompt "Select file:" default location (alias DefaultPath))
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate theFile to folder DestFolder
end tell
```

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you so much for the quick help.